# Getting neighbors of hex tiles in 3D space

Tags: unity, mathematics, hexagonal-grid

I have a hex tiled model like attached below. Each of the hex tiles are separate objects meaning I can access each of the hex tiles individually inside Unity

[image]

Now in my program I want to be able to get the 6 neighboring tiles of the selected tile. At first I thought I would get the 6 edges of the current tile and then check to see if any of the remaining tiles have those edges in common but that would be very expensive if I want to compute neighbors of all the tiles.

Any ideas??

Comment: One of the best lessons I learned a job or two ago was to keep a little separation between the data model (hex grid math) and visual representation, and to ease going back and forth with a mapping layer.  While it seems like a big waste of resources, being organized like that solves many problems like the one you're experiencing.

Comment: Yes I agree. But basically what I am trying to do is colorize my hex tiles with random colors but I want some of my neighbors to have the same color creating a region. The model was built in Houdini and imported as FBX with Maya. So I am stuck working with what I have at the moment. But I am trying to find the simplest solution possible even if its not highly efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see the hex game objects have a mesh collider. So you can use [SphereCastAll](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCastAll.html) using your hex center position as origin and hex radius * 2 as radius to grab every neighbors colliders.

It's surely not the most elegant way to do it but it sure avoid headaches :)

Comment: Thanks! I have never used SphereCast in my programs. I will look into it but I assume it works like Raycast

Comment: Though I am not sure how I could use spherecast if I would want to get neighbors of all my tiles. It would be like constantly changing the position of the source of the spherecast around the sphere

Comment: SphereCast is a good option if you want, for example, to find the neighbor on user input. If players click on a specific hex, then you SphereCastAll to act / display the neighbors. I thought you wanted to perform that kind of action.

Comment: Actually, if you save neighbors in a list it won't cost a lot as you could easily retrieve already visited neighbors.

Comment: Can you please give a use case scenario for such neighbor search?

Comment: Okay so what I was trying to do was when initially the level loads up, all my tiles as you see in the image get randomly filled with textures/ colors but I wanted them to be filled in regions and not just individual hexes which is why I wanted to get neighbors of a tile and fill them with the same color. I finally figured it out using Physics.OverlapSphere which got me neighbors based on my current hex radius :)

Comment: Ho great! Glad it helped. Note that if you need to travel through all your hex with spherecast only once (at start) this technique is OK on a performance side. However it could require a lot of computation if the number of hex is too high (hundreds... Maybe thousands, worth to try). In that case I suggest you to run spherecast by batches instead of all at once.

Answer (score 0):

you could keep references to them in a kind of an array like this so you'd get the neighbours just with indexing, like in a 2d grid: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661169/finding-adjacent-neighbors-on-a-hexagonal-grid and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585135/hexagonal-tiles-and-finding-their-adjacent-neighbourghs/15524441#15524441

Comment: I thought of storing and indexing them in an array. Well I already have stored them in a Map for another part of the game. But I don't understand how by storing them in an array would I be able to reference their neighbors because they would all get randomly stored in the array.

Comment: Don't store them randomly but ordered like in those links. So then you can do [current_index + 1] and such to get the neighbours directly.